# Is it possible to TeamCity Build Log file and mail it

Tags: teamcity

I am working on TeamCity, 
There are lot of failures in the my TestCase Automation,
I want to get the Build.log file,
I dont know the location of Build.log.

can some one please tell me where is this file location in Build Agent.

Answer (score 0):

To get the build log you'll need its build id and place it into the following URL:

`http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=BUILD_ID`

It is also possible to get the build log as the zip file using
`http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId=BUILD_ID&archived=true`

Just replace `BUILD_ID` with the desired build id.

For the detailed info, you may refer to the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Log#BuildLog-downloadBuildLog)